# Import bacpac from SQL Azure into local server fails.

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, azure-sql-database

[image: Importing .bacpac fails]

We are trying to import a bacpac into a local SQL 2017 instance but it gives the following error. This suddenly started happening, previously we didn't have any problem with it so I can't think of any change that could have caused this.

Copying the SQL database via the portal into another SQL Azure server still works thou.

This is a rather big database (12GB of data, bacpac is around 900mb thou).

I'm really baffled why he is giving me some sort of SQL Server 2014 error.

My current SQL server version:

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0  (Build 16299: )

Comment: I'm not sure if this is it or not, but check the compatibility level on the database you are exporting from. That could be leading to this issue.

Comment: @GrantFritchey Apparently it's level 100. I'm going to see if I can change this to maybe 140 and see if I can export/import. I'm going to run the export tonight and check tomorrow.

Comment: @GrantFritchey Still have the issued. Tried the 140 en 120, both no succes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not a permanent solution but by removing the FK constraints it could export and import the database. It was all focused around 1 rather large table.

I have no idea what's the possible underlying issue here. Now I have to copy the production database to another server on Azure, remove the constraints there and back-up that database instead but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the  latest versions of SSMS, then try to run the wizard again. Please download the latest version from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms).

Comment: Still have the same issue after installing the latest version.